# Dependent dropdown is returning [object object] using ajax in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have two dropdown City and City Area. I want to fill City area drop-down based on the selected value of City.

Route:

```
  Route::get('create-profile', 'ProfileController@index');
  Route::get('create-profile/city_area/{id}', 'ProfileController@city_area');
```

Primary Dropdown is : City

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-md-push-1">
<select name="city" id="city">
<option value="">--- Select City ---</option>
 @foreach($city as $city)
  <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->city_name}}</option>
 @endforeach
 </select></div>
```

Dependent Dropdown is

```
     <div class="inp_sec">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label for="r3">City Area</label>
      </div><div class="col-xs-7 col-md-push-1">
      <select name="city_area" id="city_area"></select></div></div>
```

Ajax for dependend dropdown is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="city"]').on('change', function() {
        var cityID = $(this).val();
        if(cityID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'create-profile/city_area/'+cityID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="city_area"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="city_area"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="city_area"]').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Php Code to fetch data of dependent dropdown is

```
public function city_area($id)
{
$city_area= DB::table('czech_area')->where('citi_id',$id)- 
>select('id','area_name')->get();
    return json_encode($city_area);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see **[object object]**, it's a clear sign of an object-to-string conversion.

**city_area()** function returns list of objects, that you later encode with JSON. Therefore, the **value** variable you use to fill **city_area** dropdown is a Javascript object, not a string. You need to specify the properties of this object you want to use - **id** and **area_name** in your case:

```
$('select[name="city_area"]').append('<option value="'+ value.id +'">'+ value.area_name +'</option>');
```

Comment: if I am using thing, dependent dropdown is showing, 'undefined' values for all rows

Comment: Could you paste what "data" variable contains? The one returned from the call to city_area

Comment: by the way, you shouldn't have to encode JSON manually in city_area - Laravel will do that automatically for you

Comment: on selection first dropdown its returning [{"id":22,"area_name":"Praha 2"},{"id":21,"area_name":"Praha 1"}] (without json) and [{"id":22,"area_name":"Praha 2"},{"id":21,"area_name":"Praha 1"}] (with json)

Comment: Do you get only one value in the `city_area` dropdown or more? Could you console.log `value` in the `$.each` callback?

Comment: data: (2) […]
​​
0: {…}
​​​
area_name: "Praha 2"
​​​
id: 22
​​​
__proto__: {…}
​​
1: {…}
​​​
area_name: "Praha 1"
​​​
id: 21

Comment: this code is working fine at this tutorial  view-source:http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/myform

Comment: In this demo API returns completely different structure than the one you're returning from your API

Comment: i am using same this tutorial https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-make-simple-dependent-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-in-laravel-5example.html

Comment: i did not find difference, pease help me